# how can i implement clearTiimeout after the function fires 10 times? simulate a dice roll

Tags: javascript

using javascript, i'm trying to simulate a dice roll. i'm using setTimeout but i want to do a clearTimeout after the function has run a set number of times, like say 10 for example. here's how i want it to work.

the user clicks a button. then they see a series of dice values (1-6 obviously) being displayed in the div. then, after about say, 10 times the function stops.

how can that be accomplished? the code i have so far is pretty simple.

```
function rollDice(){
diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
$('.dice-display').html(diceVal);
setTimeout(rollDice, 500);
```

//clear timeout after 10 times
    }

```
$('.rollDiceButton').click(function(){
rollDice();

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ideal use case for a closure:

```
var rollDice = ( function rollDiceClosure(){
    var iterations = 0;

    return function rollDice(){
        var diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

        $('.dice-display').html(diceVal);

        if( ++iterations >= 10 ){
            setTimeout(rollDice, 500);
        }
    }
}() );
```

The closure creates a space for the `iterations` variable. Before the `setTimeout` statement, `iterations` is increased by one. If it's equal or over 10, it won't set the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

```
var numTimes = 0; //Create a variable that will be incremented
function rollDice(){
    diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    $('.dice-display').html(diceVal);
    if (numTimes < 10) setTimeout(rollDice, 500); //only setTimeout if it's been rolled less than 10 times
    numTimes++; //increment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "setInterval" instead of "setTimeout".  "setTimeout" will only perform one function call after the initial timer.

```
$('.rollDiceButton').click(function(){
   var counter = 0;
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter < 10){
            diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
            $('.dice-display').html(diceVal);
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
}, 500);
```

Initialize a counter in your click event.  The counter is ticked by one every half a second (500 milliseconds).  Once 10 repetiions have been reached, the timer is stopped using "clearInterval"

Comment: on the generate random num, the 6+1 is necessary, as without it will generate a 0.